# Discworld quote about an "old couple" who having said everything to each other, can finally go about living their lives

Tags: discworld

There was a quote about an old couple (I believe it was Death and the character played by David Jason, I forget his name), who having lived together for a long time, and having said everything, are now finally living their lives in harmony without all that unnecessary chit chat.

Does anyone know it, and where it is from?

Comment: I think I remember that about the relationship between Death and Albert, and it was mentioned in Mort.  I don't have a good way to verify this right now though.

Comment: @JMac - Yes, Albert - I couldn't remember his name. Maybe somebody will be able to recall a direct quote.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This is indeed Death and Albert, from *Mort*

(bolding mine)

> Death strode into the stable, stooping a little to clear the ceiling. Albert nodded, not in any
>   subservient way, Mort noticed, but simply out of form. Mort had met one or two servants, on the rare
>   occasions he’d been taken into town, and Albert wasn’t like any of them. He seemed to act as though
>   the house really belonged to him and its owner was just a passing guest, something to be tolerated like
>   peeling paintwork or spiders in the lavatory. Death put up with it too, as though **he and Albert had
>   said everything that needed to be said a long time ago and were simply content, now, to get on with
>   their jobs with the minimum of inconvenience all round**. To Mort it was rather like going for a walk
>   after a really bad thunderstorm—everything was quite fresh, nothing was particularly unpleasant, but
>   there was the sense of vast energies just expended.

I found it by searching for *discworld old couple "said everything"*